# Where can i find a good book that teaches MCMC in R?

Tags: r, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, computational-statistics

I am looking for a good book that will teach me MCMC in R , in particular Block Gibbs  and Collapsed MCMC. Preferably with R pseudocode supplemented within the book as well.

Does anyone have any good recommendations ?

I  am looking for a book that teaches solely MCMC. Thanks

Comment: I think that Spiegelhalter's book is a classic and a good point to start (Markov Chain Monte Carlo in Practice)

Comment: Robert & Casella: Introducing Monte Carlo methods with R ?

Answer (score 2):

I have come across this a fair few times in my research and it has described a lot of the theory to me, and uses R:

http://www.alibris.co.uk/search/books/isbn/9781441915757

Here is a sample:

http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781441915757-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-837967-p173947407

Hope that helps!

Comment: ...which is the Robert & Casella (2009) book mentioned by Stéphane Laurent in a comment above.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try  [Using R for Data Management, Statistical Analysis, and Graphics by Horton, Kleinman (2010)](http://books.google.com/books?id=wgY1FLKogHwC) and maybe some useful information can be found in [Time Series Analysis and Its Application with R examples](http://web.njit.edu/~wguo/Math447/Time%20Series%20Analysis%20and%20Its%20Application%20with%20R%20examples.pdf).